# How to reference a specific cell value in VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble with some VBA code and was hoping that someone could help me out.

The problem is with me referencing a specific cell. The code below copies rows into another worksheet and deletes them in the worksheet it took them from based on a value.

The issue is that I want the user to be able to specify the value in a specific cell rather than coming back to a spreadhseet to alter and realter it (it's just a quality of life thing).

Here's the code and what I mean:

```
Sub Kappa()
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xCell As Range
Dim I As Long
Dim J As Long
Dim K As Long
I = Worksheets("Data").UsedRange.Rows.Count
J = Worksheets("Archives").UsedRange.Rows.Count
If J = 1 Then
   If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Archives").UsedRange) = 0 Then J = 0
End If
Set xRg = Worksheets("Data").Range("I1:I" & I)
On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For K = 1 To xRg.Count
    If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = Application.Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Worksheets("Data").Range("M5") Then
        xRg(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Archives").Range("A" & J + 1)
        xRg(K).EntireRow.Delete
        If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = Application.Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Worksheets("Data").Range("M5") Then
            K = K - 1
        End If
        J = J + 1
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True End Sub
```

What happens with this is that it spins (I couldn't even get an error!).

If you alter the code to say something along the lines of:

```
    Sub Kappa()
Dim xRg As Range
Dim xCell As Range
Dim I As Long
Dim J As Long
Dim K As Long
I = Worksheets("Data").UsedRange.Rows.Count
J = Worksheets("Archives").UsedRange.Rows.Count
If J = 1 Then
   If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Archives").UsedRange) = 0 Then J = 0
End If
Set xRg = Worksheets("Data").Range("I1:I" & I)
On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For K = 1 To xRg.Count
    If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "Alpha" Then
        xRg(K).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Archives").Range("A" & J + 1)
        xRg(K).EntireRow.Delete
        If CStr(xRg(K).Value) = "Alpha" Then
            K = K - 1
        End If
        J = J + 1
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True End Sub
```

It works like a charm.

Is there any way of repurposing this so it references a value in a cell?

Comment: This seems to be a bit overly complicated for a single cell, but how exactly do you want to specify things and what exactly is then supposed to happen?

Comment: This is overly complicated and difficult to figure out what you've not told us.  Is this cell you want to get text from in a whole separate workbook called Book1.xlsm?  It seems like it is because its Data!M5 overlaps with what you are deleting.  Also you seem to have discovered that deleting rows renumbers everything because you are manipulating loop variables inside your loop.  Just reverse your loop For K = xRg.Count to 1 Step -1